# Java Enumeration on Hash Table

Tags: java, hashtable, enumeration

I'm a CS student working on a project about hashtables in Java. We are creating our own hashtable and I've already completed it using linked lists to manage collisions.

However my professor is  asking us to include a method within my hash table class that returns an Enumeration to go through the keys in the hash table. I'm having trouble understanding how to do this. I've Googled enumeration and all I'm getting is enum results.

Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT: So if I'm reading this correctly I should have my hash table class implement Enumeration, and then define nextElement() and hasMoreElements() within my class? My getkeys() method that returns an Enumeration just returns the hashtable class?

Comment: This link may help: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Enumeration.html. The basic idea is to create an object that can be asked for the "next element" until such time as it has returned each element in a collection (in this case your key set.)

Comment: Ask your professor to forget about `Hashtable`s, and use more modern implementations of the `Map` interface :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use java.util.Hashtable implementation as an example. Its keys() method returns Enumeration